# Android Studio 1.2.2 giving error : peer not authenticated

Tags: android, sdk, peer

I am new to Android app development, and I am following a online tutorial from a website. The instructor there provided with a few sample projects that are to be modified further. Every time I open the projects I get the following error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download artifact 'junit-dep.jar (junit:junit-dep:4.10)'
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit-dep/4.10/junit-dep-4.10.jar'.
>   peer not authenticated

I am able to access " https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit-dep/4.10/ " from my browser. I searched a lot but still nothing solves out my problem.
I am running the Android studio with administrator privileges,(as stated by someone in a similar post in here) but it didn't work out.

Comment: Which online tutorial and which project are you trying to load?

Comment: The one in edx.org , titled - "COMP107x Introduction to Mobile Application Development using Android" Its the 2nd week of the course . Is there a way to just include the artifact file ( the jar file)  directly into the project rather than making the sdk to download it .